# Significance of table in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, routes, kernel, iptables

I have a fundamental question with respect to iptables processing logic.

I see iptables have chains PREROUTING, INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD and POSTROUTING. And these chains are present in multiple tables.

Based on what I have understood so far, the packet arrives into PREROUTING, then based on routing rules if the packet is meant for the local machine enters INPUT chain. Else it goes to FORWARD chain and then later on POSTROUTING.

But my fundamental question is, if there are multiple INPUT rules in multiple tables. In what order are the tables processed in ? I read that the first table would be raw. But what about the rest ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For understanding the traversing of each table please go through this guide it would help you understand the flow http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/traversingoftables.html

INPUT chains are used only in Filter and Mangle table(used for alteration of packets)

Thanks & Regards,
Alok

Comment: Thanks that helps. I should've googled a little more.